# Whether I can have common leader board for both iOs and Android using Google Play Game Service?

Tags: android, ios, google-play-games, leaderboard

My question is how to keep common leader board. Whether Google Play Game Services is way to keep it for both iOs and Android?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the app ID, bundle name, leaderboards keys are same, common leaderboards should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in that iOS does not default to allow for the publically sharing of activity.  This means that even though you may have requested the appropriate scopes in the platform definition for sharing of info, iOS will not publically be doing that.

Also - the leaderboard to be used through Google Play Games must have its **Enable tamper protection** set to **OFF** in order for the leaderboard to be shareable outside of the *Android* world (e.g.; Apple, web).  If this property is set to off, the *All* setting for the leaderboard UI will show all users' high scores, except for the iPhone users which have not permitted their activity to be displayed publically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. It is technically feasible to implement the leaderboard however there is a massive caveat being that a gmail account that has not previously registered a Gamer Id will not be able to sign in.  This is not mentioned in the docs.  This issue is particularly insidious in that many people, myself included, used the same account for testing on android and ios. As long as you signed in on android first will then be successful on iOS as well. Which is great if your game targets people who use android and iOS simultaneously lol.